# general sibling selector used to style target:pseudo class

Tags: css

OK I have spent 3 days looking for the answer and I still can't get my head round it so please  could someone take a look at this tutorial and explain to me why he said this -

> `"The reason for having such an “unordered” structure by adding the header to the end, is that we make the navigation “reachable” using the general sibling selector (~), so that we can color the respective items differently."` I would be very happy!

[tutorial in question](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/30/page-transitions-with-css3/)

If I move the Header with the navigation section from the bottom of the html document then whatever content section is beneath it will not get the styling applied to it.

Please help a confused noob!

Comment: What they said. And I don't think it's a good idea. The markup defines the structure of the document and is the most important part of it (apart from the content of course). CSS should be subordinate to that; you should not let your markup be ruled by your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

> The `~` combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
>   element **only if it is preceded** by the first, and both share a common
>   parent.

So in the following selectors:

```css
#home:target ~ #header #navigation #link-home
```

if `#header` is **succeeded** in the markup by the content addressed by `#home:target`, it won't be matched.

Comment: Many thanks, I finally understand it now. It was driving me quietly mad!

Answer (score 1):

The General Sibling Selector is available in CSS3, and the combinator used in this selector is a tilde character (`~`).

The selector matches elements that are siblings of a given element.

In this particular scenario, the author wants the header to be a subsequent sibling of the other class so that he can target the respective links. This would not be possible if the header was defined in the beginning of the HTML.Technically if you have the header at the beginning of the file it is still a sibling of the other div's because they are all the same HTML element (`<div>`). However in this case for the `~` to work the the header element has to occur after the other element in the HTML markup.

Check [this page](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) for a detailed explanation on how this works and check the [official documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) also.

```
#home:target ~ #header #navigation #link-home
                     OR
#portfolio:target ~ #header #navigation #link-portfolio
                     OR
#about:target ~ #header #navigation #link-about
                     OR
#contact:target ~ #header #navigation #link-contact
```

Also this can be all targeted together like follows

```
#home:target ~ #header #navigation #link-home,
#portfolio:target ~ #header #navigation #link-portfolio,
#about:target ~ #header #navigation #link-about,
#contact:target ~ #header #navigation #link-contact{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: *"since he has defined the header at the end of the HTML it ends up being a child element of all the previous elements"* - how so? we cannot affect the markup hierarchy in the stylesheet.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Its rather a sibling

Comment: Thank you for the help, the 2 answers given have helped me to understand it finally!